# What's the easiest way to request a list of web pages from a web server one by one?

Tags: node.js, automation, web-crawler

Given a list of URLs, how does one implement the following automated task (assuming windows and ubuntu are the available O/Ses)?  Are there existing types of tools that can make implementing this easier or do this out of the box?

```
log in with already-known credentials
for each specified url 
  request page from server
  wait for page to be returned (no specific max time limit)
  if request times out, try again (try x times)
  if server replies, or x attempts failed, request next url
end for each
// Note: this is intentionally *not* asynchronous to be nice to the web-server.
```

Background: I'm implementing a worker tool that will request pages from a web server so the data those pages need to crunch through will be cached for later.  The worker doesn't care about the resulting pages' contents, although it might care about HTML status codes.  I've considered a phantom/casper/node setup, but am not very familiar with this technology and don't want to reinvent the wheel (even though it would be fun).

Comment: What's wrong with using the http or request modules?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not familiar with what you're talking about.  Which request modules?  Node?

Comment: the http module http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request

Comment: the request module https://github.com/mikeal/request

Comment: The request module looks promising. Thanks the links.  Do you think a node server is overkill for this task?

Comment: I move my offerings to a post. I use node for what you are doing in an app. It wasn't overkill for me, but I was also doing more than saving the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request pages easily with the http module.

[Here's an example.](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request)

Some people prefer the request module available in npm.

[Here's a link to the github page](https://github.com/mikeal/request)

If you need more than that, you can use phantomjs.

[Here's a link to the github page for bridging node and phantom](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node)

However, you could also look for simple cli commands for making requests such as `wget` or `curl`.

Comment: I decided to go the node route, but instead of having node do the crawling I spawned a Casper process.  Node handles responding to job requests and providing status updates.  I think using Phantom/Casper separately will make it a bit more flexible in the long run.  Decided against Node's phantom modules because it seems like people have had mixed success with Casper and node since they use different javascript engines.